# How to add the working directory in PYTHONPATH in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am a complete newbee to python. So, I need to know how to add the current working directory in PYTHONPATH.

Comment: It should already be there, assuming by CWD you mean the directory where you started Python. To check, write `import sys` then `print(sys.path)` and look for either a blank entry `''` or a single dot `'.'`

Comment: He is right, it is already there. Show your short code snippet which doesn't work. I think the reason is different.

Comment: Thnx @darthbith I figured it out